# 'or', 'and' in ng-model angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items, some of them has property value, some has property default. And I need to bind it into the input[text] with ng-repeat.
Array is looks like:

```
$scope.arr = [
 {value:'name'},
 {value:'dog'},
 {default:'cat'},
 {value:'lastName'},
 {default:'ring'}
];
```

And in html:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in arr'>
 <input type='text' ng-model='item.value || item.default'>
</div>
```

It works, but I have error message in console "[ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/nonassign?p0=item.value%20%7C%7CNaNtem.default&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20ng-model%3D%item.value%20%7C%7C%item.default%22%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%3E". Because ng-model doesn't work with expression.. 
Perhaps there is another way to solve it?

[Plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/PoACZ0W71EPLbnHxHAEE?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in arr'>
   <input type='text' ng-hide='item.default' ng-model='item.value'>
   <input type='text' ng-show='item.default' ng-model='item.default'>
</div>
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/43veSbpTL10usKdhODm1?p=preview).

Comment: thx! It's good idea, but when value = '' (empty), ng-show will hide this field. So perhaps I need to make some check like `ng-show='fieldCheck(item)'`, and `$scope.fieldCheck = function(item) {if('value' in item) return true}` - for example..

Comment: @YoroDiallo Wait a minute, are you interested to show both fields? What is your final result that you expect?

Comment: yes, I need to paste all objects into input. Every object in array have default or value property, and it can be empty or have some value, but I need to bind it in input.. so when `value = ''` i can fill it from input (write something in input)

Comment: I am not really sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you want to have two input fields one for value another for default, then just remove the `ng-show`. If you want to show one or another whichever is populated, then the solution from my answer.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I understand. WIll do a quick update on my answer just now.

Comment: @YoroDiallo So in this case, you just hide the input for value, when the default is populated. Otherwise the input for `value` will be there either empty or populated depending what you have in the model.

Comment: @YoroDiallo, I added an example forked from your Plunker. Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for help!) it works, but when I remove 'ring' from 'default' field (so default = ''), and write smth in input[text] it add a new property 'value'..

Comment: Of ourse, because the ng-model that is shown when the default is not present is bound to `value`. So you are looking to edit both properties? It would be helpful if you can describe your scenarios more detailed.

Comment: I try to change a little bit your code like `<input type='text' ng-show='item.default || item.default === ""' ng-model='item.default'>` it looks ugly but it works) thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a second array, using only single type of object and bound it to the view.
Then, you can watch for changes and re-assign values to your original array.
It is more a MVVM approach (creating a "viewModel") that intermediate between the controller model and the view.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.valueOrDefault = function (item){
  return item.value|| item.default;
}`

and HTML

`<div ng-repeat='item in arr'>
 <input type='text' ng-model='valueOrDefault(item)'>
</div>`